# ContinuedFloat, and Subfloat

Tags: numbering, captions, subfloats

In my thesis I have a lot of figures with a common caption and multiple subfigures (a,b,c..etc). I wanted to split them between the pages because I don't want to fit them all in one page, therefore I used the commands `\subfloat` and `\ContinuedFloat`. It helped, BUT:

1. The numbering of the figures started from 0, i.e. Fig.1.0 which it shouldn't.
2. The numbering was not in sequence, it started like that: Fig.1.0, Fig.1.1, Fig.1.2, then went back Fig.1.1, then Fig.1.2....etc and even in the subfigures the numbering was not in sequence, it was like: Fig.1.0 (a) and Fig.1.1 (b) instead of Fig.1.0 (b)....

This is the code I used:

```
%\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
%\subfigure[]{
\centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{fig1.eps} } \, 
\label{int1}}%
\end{figure}
%\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h!]
\ContinuedFloat
%\subfigure[]{
\centering
\subfloat{\includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{fig2.eps} } \, 
\label{int2}}%
\caption{my figures (a) and (b).}
\label{int}
\end{figure}
```

Then it was a matter of copying and pasting for the other figures (and subfigures).

Answer (score 23):

Unfortunately the algorithm of `\ContinuedFloat` offered by the subfig package is based on the assumption that every figure has a `\caption`. For that reason the `caption` package offers a command called `\phantomcaption` (without any arguments) since version 3.2 which does not typeset a caption but will fulfill the needs of `\ContinuedFloat`.

For usage with version 3.1 of the caption package one can define `\phantomcaption` as:

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand\phantomcaption{\caption@refstepcounter\@captype}
\makeatother
```

Since this uses `\providecommand` it will not break with future versions of the caption package.

BTW: The current version 3.3 of the caption package offers a `\ContinuedFloat` without the need of a `\caption`, but since the subfig package comes with its own definition of `\ContinuedFloat` (overriding the one defined by the `caption` package) you'll still need `\phantomcaption` when using the `subfig` package.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{fig1.eps} \, 
\label{int1}}
\phantomcaption  % <=== This line added to compensate for the missing \caption
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=1.0\columnwidth]{fig2.eps} \, 
\label{int2}}%
\caption{my figures (a) and (b).}
\label{int}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```