# Issues with figure numbering and\ContinuedFloat command

Tags: floats, subfloats

I am having an issues with the `subfig` and `\ContinuedFloat` command.  I have a figure that has 4 subfigures.  They are too large to fit on one page.  I have tried using the `\ContinuedFloat` command to split it over two pages.  It makes the images look correct and do what I want, but it is changing the figure number.  I.e.  the figure is supposed to be 3.4 (when I don't use the `\ContinuedFloat` command it is, but consequently runs off the page) but when I use the `\ContinuedFloat` command, it changes the figure number to 3.3  So now the figure looks right, but I have two figure 3.3.  I am at a loss.  Here is how I am coding it (I realize you don't have my images so it can't be run by someone else).  If there is an issue with the coding, I would greatly appreciate if someone could point it out.

```
\documentclass[botnum, fleqn]{unmeethesis}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[!htpb]
\centering
\subfigure[a]{
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_1_load}
}\\
\subfigure[b]{
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_1_unload}
}\\
\subfigure[c]{
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_2_load}
}\\
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\ContinuedFloat
\subfigure[d]{
\includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_2_unload}
}
\caption{This is my caption}
\label{ML_contour_2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that includes the needed preamble.

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/how-do-i-mark-code-blocks) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Note that an MWE actually means that community members can copy-and-paste your code into their editor, press compile and immediately view the document. This is not the case with your code snippet. It doesn't have a preamble, `\documentclass` or a `document` environment. You may think those are elementary changes to the existing snippet, but it just helps others in starting with a working piece of code.

Comment: Sorry!  I am new to this.  I hope the new edit helps.

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15647/continuedfloat-and-subfloat

Answer (score 9):

Your code snippet does not include a caption for the first `figure` environment, and therefore you technically don't need a `\ContinuedFloat`. Or, in a more general setting, a call to `\ContinuedFloat` is only needed when you have a caption on all the pages of the broken up float.

If you don't want a caption for the first `figure`, then don't include `\caption` and also drop `\ContinuedFloat` from the second.

I'm therefore guessing you must be after:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{subfig}% http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig
%\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!htpb]
  \centering
  \subfloat[a]{%
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_1_load}%
  }\\
  \subfloat[b]{%
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_1_unload}%
  }\\
  \subfloat[c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_2_load}%
  }
  \caption{This is my caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \ContinuedFloat
  \subfloat[d]{%
    \includegraphics[width=4.5in]{figures1/ML_cycle_2_unload}%
  }
  \caption{(continued) This is my caption}
  \label{ML_contour_2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You didn't mention anything about [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) compatibility, or List of Figure entries, although these can be compensated for/incorporated.

Comment: That isn't exactly what I am looking for.  I want all four of the subfigures to have the same caption, so I only want the caption showing once and one fig #.  In the caption, I reference a, b, c, and d.  I have no idea what the hyperref compatibility is.  I do have a List of Figures, and the entries are messed up when I use the \ContinuedFloat.  Sorry if this confuses it more.  I am new to using Latex. Using the fixed code, I am now getting body text between the \end{figure} and the \begin{figure}

Comment: Which of the two figures should carry the `\caption` then? Do you want only one caption to show up in the List of Figures? Do you want any of the subfigures to show up in the List of Figures? Since `figure`s are floats, they'll move around, so it's possible that body text will end up between the two `figure`s. I assume you don't want this. Read [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2275/5764) and [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/5764)