# Negative numbers being assigned to figures

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, numbering

I am using pdflatex distribution. I have many figures in the my latex document.

For some reason 
the numbering stars from Figure 1 ,then Figure 2. It then goes to Figure 0, -1, -2 and so on.

The subfigures are labelled in the reveres order, (d), (c), (b) ,(a) .
Here is one of the examples:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \caption{Some caption }\label{fig:figure1}
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{3.pdf}
   \caption{Less Reflective Object}\label{fig:lessreflec}
   \caption*{More text}
 \end{subfigure} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
 \centering
 \ContinuedFloat
 \begin{subfigure}[h]{\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{4.pdf}
    \caption{Another caption} 
    \caption*{ some text}   
    \label{fig:irkey}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages.

Comment: Related (if using [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig)): [ContinuedFloat, and Subfloat](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15647/5764)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The intent of `\ContinuedFloat` (of [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption)) is to drop the environment counter by 1 and store the state of the sub-environment numbering so that it can be carried over to a subsequent floating environment (otherwise they would typically be reset when the environment counter is incremented - which happens when you issue `\caption`). Here's a more structured/commented look at it when looking at the `figure` and `subfigure` environments:

```
\begin{figure}% <-- sets the caption type to figure
  \caption{..}% <-- increments the caption type counter (figure in this case)
  % figure content and possible subfigures
\end{figure}

% textual content

\begin{figure}% <-- sets the caption type to figure
  \ContinuedFloat% <-- decreases the caption type counter by 1 (figure in this case)
  % figure content and possible subfigures
\end{figure}
```

The problem with this is that subsequent `figure`s with `\caption` will not have the correct counter, since it's reduced with every issue of `\ContinuedFloat` *if* you don't have an accompanying `\caption` to step it again. That's why `subcaption` offers `\phantomcaption` if you don't want a full caption but still have appropriate numbering - the missing step. So, your full usage should actually resemble:

```
\begin{figure}% <-- sets the caption type to figure
  \caption{..}% <-- increments the caption type counter (figure in this case)
  % figure content and possible subfigures
\end{figure}

% textual content

\begin{figure}% <-- sets the caption type to figure
  \ContinuedFloat% <-- decreases the caption type counter by 1 (figure in this case)
  % figure content and possible subfigures
  \phantomcaption% <-- increases the caption type counter by 1 (figure in this case)
\end{figure}
```

Without a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv), it is not easy to understand why your `subfigure`s may be out of sync.

Comment: my pdftex version(3.14) did not support `\phantomcaption` , so I added `\caption` after each `\ContinuedFloat` to solve my problem. Thank you!