# How to arrange a figure consisting of four subfigures?

Tags: floats

Two subfigures in one page. This figure take two page.

(a)

(b)

---

Page 2

(c)

(d)
figure 1. The caption of this figure.

Comment: Do you mean you have four subfigures that you want on one page with two rows of two subfigures side by side?

Comment: I'm not providing a solution, but I think this is a bad idea. Your readers will be looking for a caption on page 1. By denying them one, you run the risk of confusing them.

Comment: @Jubobs, your advice is sense. But I do have four big figures. And they are related. So I can not divide them. And one subfigure is on a single line. My tutor said it would be clear in this way.

Comment: @pierre, Thank you. hi, No, $4 \times 1$.

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110153/multi-page-figure-with-subcaption-package

Comment: @ thank you, it 1:30am. I am going to finish this paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you just want

```
\usepackage{capt-of}
```

then

```
% get on left side of a 2-page spread
\clearpage
\ifodd\value{page}\mbox{}\clearpage\fi

% two images on this page
\includegraphics{f1}

\vspace{...}
\includegraphics{f2}

\clearpage

% two more images on this page
\includegraphics{f3}

\vspace{...}
\includegraphics{f4}

 % caption
\vspace{...}
\captionof{figure}{........}

\clearpage
```

Comment: thank you. How could make them at the center. I also have to add sub caption. I try but there are mistakes.

Comment: `\begin{center}` `\end{center}`  for sub cations you could just add text `a) this is the first bit` or if you want the subcaptions in the list of figures etc, look to the subfigure rr caption packages.

Comment: hi, thank you for your comment. I know you mean.\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.75\linewidth,height=0.35\linewidth]{lmtlInsensitiveLosstau=10-5n.eps} 
    \caption{Insensitive Loss $\lambda=10^{-5}$} 
    \label{fig:mtlnli5} 
  \end{subfigure}  But if I revise this (add subfigur) in the frame you gave to me, mistakes occur.