# Filling a page with figures

Tags: text-manipulation, fillbetween

I have a text and then a bunch of figures. I would like to fill A page with all the figures so the text would continue AFTER this page. In other words I would need something like this :

Page 1 : text

Page 2 : Figures (don't want any text)

Pages 3 : following of text of Page 1

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Floating figure can be put in page with the option `\begin{figure}[p]`

Comment: Thanks it is almost what I would like to do but the text does not continue after the figure.It is like \pagebreak whereas I would like something more like I described in my post

Comment: When you say "Page 2 : Figures (don't want any text)", do you mean that there are no captions?  If that is the case, perhaps this question might be of interest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168748/optimal-arrangement-of-pictures-boxes-in-a-page

Comment: Thank you but no actually I just meant no "standard" text, captions can be present

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the [placeins](http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/placeins/placeins-doc.pdf) package.

```
\usepackage{placeins}
\begin{document}
page 1, text

\pagebreak
\FloatBarrier % This command was enabled by placeins. The floating figure will not pass it.
\begin{figure}
...
\end{figure}
\pagebreak
\FloatBarrier

page 3, text
\end{document}
```

The `placeins` package enables the use of `\FloatBarrier` (must use capital F and B). Floating figures will not pass over `\FloatBarrier`.