# Figure number of three figures are same

Tags: floats

I have five figures in a chapter. The figure numbers of first 3 figures are correct i.e. 5.1, 5.2 and 5.3 but the figure numbers of next two figures are also 5.3

The structure of first 3 figures is following:

```
        \begin{figure}[!ht]
        \centering
%%image-1
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/assignPixels/img1/image1}}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/assignPixels/img1/connectedComps}} 
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/assignPixels/img1/supPix}}
        \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/assignPixels/img1/visual}}\\               
        \caption{Assignment of pixels.}
        \label{image:assignSP}
        \end{figure}
```

Whereas the structure of next two figures is following:

```
\begin{figure}[]
%%image-1
%%Org image
        \subfloat[Original image]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/assignPixels/img1/image1}}\\
%%Layer-1
        \subfloat[Layer-1, Subgraph-1]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L1_SG1}} 
        \subfloat[Layer-1, Segmentation]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L1_VI}} 
        \subfloat[Layer-1, Saliency]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L1_Sal}}\\      
%%Layer-2       
        \subfloat[Layer-2, Subgraph-1]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_SG1}}
        \subfloat[Layer-2, Subgraph-2]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_SG2}}  
        \subfloat[Layer-2, Segmentation]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_VI}} 
        \subfloat[Layer-2, Saliency]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L2_Sal}}\\      
        \phantomcaption     
        \end{figure}
%%mages on the new page
%%mages on the new page
\begin{figure}[]
        \ContinuedFloat
        \subfloat[Layer-4, Segmentation]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_VI}} 
        \subfloat[Layer-4, Saliency]{\includegraphics[width = 2in, height = 3cm, keepaspectratio]{bilder/concepts/GNGhierarchy/img1/L4_Sal}}
        \caption{corresponding maps.}
        \label{image:Hierarchy}
\end{figure}
```

**It can be noted that in the last two figures, I have used the concept of `\ContinuedFloat`.**

Comment: Are you loading both the `caption` and `subfigure` packages?

Comment: @Mico: \usepackage[caption = false]{subfig}

Comment: How or where is `\phantomcaption` defined?

Answer (score 2):

Without a complete example, it is impossible to be sure. However, I suspect the problem is the result of the following 2 points:

- without a `\caption` or `\phantomcaption`, `\ContinuedFloat` will not work;
- `\phantomcaption` is defined by `caption` which you have told `subfig` ought not be loaded - hence, it is undefined.

Note that compiling non-stop is great but it is not the way to diagnose problems. ***Ignore errors at your peril.*** In this case, LaTeX will have failed compilation with an error which would have told you precisely the problem. If you must ignore errors, you have to read the `.log` assiduously not only when there is an obvious problem, but to find problems of a more subtle variety.

Here's my version of your example, borrowing code from [Zarko's efforts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248481/):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelsep=space,
labelfont={sf,bf},
textfont=sf,
caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx,kantlipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  %        \centering
  %%image-1
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{Assignment of pixels 1.}
  \label{image:assignSP1}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  %        \centering
  %%image-1
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{Assignment of pixels 2.}
  \label{image:assignSP2}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  %        \centering
  %%image-1
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{Assignment of pixels 3.}
  \label{image:assignSP3}
\end{figure}

\kant[1]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  %%image-2
  \subfloat[Original image1] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-11, Subgraph-1] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-11, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-11, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
  %%Layer-2
  \subfloat[Layer-12, Subgraph-1] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-12, Subgraph-2] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-12, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-12, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \phantomcaption
\end{figure}
\vfill

%%mages on the new page
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \subfloat[Layer-14, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-14, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{corresponding maps 1.}
  \label{image:Hierarchy1}
\end{figure}

\kant[2-3]

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  %%image-2
  \subfloat[Original image2] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-21, Subgraph-1] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-21, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-21, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
  %%Layer-2
  \subfloat[Layer-22, Subgraph-1] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-22, Subgraph-2] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-22, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-22, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \phantomcaption
\end{figure}
\vfill

%%mages on the new page
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \subfloat[Layer-24, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-24, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
  \caption{corresponding maps 2.}
  \label{image:Hierarchy2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: modified MWE]

We do not actually need this much. A single figure followed by some filler text, the first part of a figure and the continuation would be quite sufficient to demonstrate the issue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[labelsep=space,
labelfont={sf,bf},
textfont=sf,
caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \caption{Assignment of pixels 1.}
  \label{image:assignSP1}
\end{figure}


\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \subfloat[Original image1] {\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-4x3}}\hfill
  \subfloat[Layer-12, Subgraph-1] {\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-4x3}}
  \phantomcaption
\end{figure}
\vfill

%%mages on the new page
\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \ContinuedFloat
  \subfloat[Layer-14, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\hfill
  \caption{corresponding maps 1.}
  \label{image:Hierarchy1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

which, if we ignore the errors and carry blithely on, gives us:

[image: modified MWE minimised]

which clearly shows the problem: figure 2 on page 2 is numbered 1.

When we try to compile this, compilation fails with the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.24   \phantomcaption

?
```

That is, it complains that `\phantomcaption` is not defined. This is bad because `\ContinuedFloat` requires a `\caption` to work. `subfig` assumes that the first part of a `figure` will always have a `\caption`. That caption increments the `figure` counter. No `\caption` means no increment. Meanwhile, `\ContinuedFloat` explicitly prevents the `\caption` in the second part from incrementing the `figure` counter.

The solution to this is `\phantomcaption` which ensures that the counter is incremented. But `subfig` does not provide this command. `caption` provides it. But by setting `caption=false`, we have told `subfig` that `caption` is not to be loaded.

For further details, see [Axel Sommerfeldt's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15693/) on this topic.

So, there are two obvious options:

1. set `caption=true`;
2. use a real `\caption`.

In the absence of more details, option 1 seems the better choice. Setting `caption=true` in the options to `subfig` resolves the issue nicely:

[image: properly counting figures]

Option 2, adding `\caption{first part}` to the first part of the `figure` achieves precisely the same result for the second part plus, of course, an additional caption for the first.

If for some reason neither of these are options, the only other choice I can see is to implement something yourself. For example adding the following to your preamble:

```
\newcommand*\phantomfigurecaption{\stepcounter{figure}}
\newcommand*\phantomtablecaption{\stepcounter{table}}
```

would allow you to use `\phantomfigurecaption` in the first part of the `figure` to achieve roughly the same result. But note that this is a hack and will be much less robust than using one of the options provided by the packages. I do not recommend doing it this way unless you really have no better option.

Comment: thanks for a detailed answer. I tried to set `caption=true` but it did not help. I will post a complete MWE example in few days.

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't provide minimal working example (MWE) I construct my own. I'm pretty sure that it differ a lot form your real document. In it I skip `\phantomcaption` and `ContinuedFloat` regardless that they can be cause of your problem (I guess that they work differently as you imagine that they should, but maybe I'm wrong).

This simplified MWE work as expected: counting of figures and sub-figures are continuously incremented:
[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[labelsep=space,
                labelfont={sf,bf},
                textfont=sf,
                caption=false]{subfig}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{figure}[!ht]
%        \centering
%%image-1
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
    \caption{Assignment of pixels.}
\label{image:assignSP}
        \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
%%image-2
\subfloat[Original image] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-1, Subgraph-1] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-1, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-1, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\\
%%Layer-2
\subfloat[Layer-2, Subgraph-1] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-2, Subgraph-2] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-2, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-2, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.24\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
        %\phantomcaption
    \caption{Assignment of pixels.}
        \end{figure}
%%mages on the new page
\begin{figure}[!ht]
        %\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[Layer-4, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-4, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
        \caption{corresponding maps.}
        \label{image:Hierarchy}
\end{figure}
%% my addition
\begin{figure}[!ht]
        %\ContinuedFloat
\subfloat[Layer-4, Segmentation] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}\hfill
\subfloat[Layer-4, Saliency] {\includegraphics[width=0.48\hsize,height=1cm]{example-image}}
        \caption{one more images.}
        \label{image:Hierarchy}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

This is actualy is not an answer, more is help for yonstruction of your WME, which exhibits your problems. Knowing it, SE community would  help you more easily.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Actually I want to provide MWE but as it a big file where I dont have any problem related to the figure number except at this particular place so, I don't know how can I provide the MWE.

Comment: Just upgrade mine with thing which you missed in it.  For example, with packages which are missed, or defined ``\phantomcaption`` and ``\ContinuedFloat``. Use ``lipsum`` or ``\blindtext`` instead of real text and ``example-image`` instead real ones.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I think that the problem is due to the \phantomcaption and ContinuedFloat. Actually, on the same section of a chapter I have 2-3 figures which are using \phantomcaption and ContinuedFloat concept because they consist of several image. Therefore, the \phantomcaption and ContinuedFloat are not able to understand that they are a part of new image. I really don't have any idea what is cause of this behaviour.

Comment: Well, I must confess, that I do not understand, why you need `\phantomcaption`. As I show you in my MWE, you don't need it at all. I suggest you (again): edit your MWE such that will show your problem. I don't know, how much I miss your expected help. Obviously my answer doesn't help you :-(

Comment: This is useful groundwork (+1) but it doesn't reproduce the problem. I take it that `\phantomcaption` is wanted because the OP wants no caption to be typeset with the first set of sub-figures belonging to a figure which breaks across pages. `\ContinuedFloat` says that these are further sub-figures belonging to the same overall figure. Your reconstruction would get the numbering wrong: there would be 7 figures rather than 5 and the sub-figure numbering would not be continuous in figure 4/5 or 6/7. So those things are needed - it's just that the OP has disabled the support for `\phantomcaption`.

Comment: @cfr, thank you for vote, I vote for your answer too. I carefully read your elaboration in your answer, but I most liked your conclusion :-). In our place we say (literary translated): "He (i.e. OP) like to invent square wheel". For me is not logical to have only sub captions without indication to which figures they belongs, so I wrongly anticipated, that my answer will indicate OP, what readers (lime me) of his paper will expect and how to do this. O.K. at least my answer was useful a bit for preparing of yours :-).

Comment: I've never split a figure over a page break. Since `\phantomcaption` exists, I guess people do it. But I agree that some indication that this is going to happen would be useful.