# Use of "hyperref" package do not let increment the figure number by "\continuedFloat"

Tags: graphics, floats, subfloats

I need to have figures with several subfigures . In some cases, the subfigures of a figure have to go to the next page. For this purpose, I have to use `\continuedFloat` but then **the figure number of image remain same (or sometimes completely weird).**

I have asked this question before [**here**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248457/figure-number-of-three-figures-are-same) and somebody also asked similar problem [**here**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15647/continuedfloat-and-subfloat) but the solutions provided to both the questions did not work for me. Therefore, I am posting a new question with minimal working example.

**IMPORTANT UPDATE:** Just now I realized that if I remove the line `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}` then, everything works fine. But if I keep that line of code then, the figure number of both the figures remain same.

**My code (MWE):**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=425.196850394pt, top=70.866141732pt,bottom=70.866141732pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}  
\raggedbottom                    
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%%%SO for th table form of images
\usepackage[caption = true,font=normalsize]{subfig}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Document Begins from here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother


\chapter{Introduction}
This chapter is about the problem of wrong figure numbers.

%%%----------------------------------------------Normal Figure----------------------%%%%%%%%%%
        \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
        \caption{Figure on a single page.}
        \end{figure}

%%%---------------------------------------------Two page Figure---------------------%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[!ht]

    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}} \\
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}} \\
    \phantomcaption
\end{figure}
%%mages on the new page
\begin{figure}[]
\ContinuedFloat
    \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}} \\    
\caption{Figure on two pages}
\label{image}
\end{figure}

%%%--------------Tabular Figure --------%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}

%%Original image
\subfloat[Original image]{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYYY}
          \includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}    \\
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}}\par\medskip

%% First Layer
\subfloat[Third layer]{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    %\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYYYY}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
        &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}  \\ 
        First image & Second image
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}}
\phantomcaption
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Figure continued%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[ht]
\ContinuedFloat
 %%Second Layer
\subfloat[Forth layer]{%
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    %\centering
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YYYYY}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
        &\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}  \\ 
        First image & Second image
    \end{tabularx}
\end{minipage}}
\caption{Figure using Tables}
\label{image}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

**No Solution yet:**

- The [**solution**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258405/48093) provided  to my question says to use `\phantomcaption` and set `caption=true` which I have already done but still the figure number of both the figures are same.
- The [**solution**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15693/48093) provided to other question is also similar and that did not work for me either.

Comment: I think `subfig` has some issues with `hyperref`, is switching to `subcaption` an option?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : By switching to it, it throws an that `Undefined control sequence \subfloat`. And, changing the whole structure will be a problem as this is just a MWE of whole big file.

Comment: Yes, switching package does require switching syntax for all subfloats, which is a downside. The upside is that it works.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : In my thesis file (quite big), the figure number were quite weird. It was like `5.1`, `5.2` `5.3` `5.2` `5.1` `5.0`. And after removing `hyperref`, it becomes `5.1`, `5.2` `5.3` `5.3` `5.3` `5.3`. So, the problem persists even after removing `hyperref`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. : Ok, please provide the example of solving this problem using `subcaption`.  I will try to make changes in my original file if it helps

Comment: `subfig` is known not to behave well with `hyperref`. Use `subcaption` as recommended by @TorbjørnT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible to make this work with `subfig` as well, but here is an example that uses `subcaption` instead. It provides, among other things, a `subfigure` environment and a `subcaption` command. The former is a `minipage`-like environment, used as

```
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{This is a sub-caption.}
\end{subfigure}
```

The latter is used instead of the normal `\caption`, and makes sub-captions instead. In general, this should only be used within a group or environment. The manual shows an example with  `minipage`s, in the below code I just added a brace pair around it and the graphic.

With the below code you get figures 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4 as expected.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=425.196850394pt, top=70.866141732pt,bottom=70.866141732pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}  
\raggedbottom                    
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Document Begins from here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother


\chapter{Introduction}
This chapter is about the problem of wrong figure numbers.

%%%----------------------------------------------Normal Figure----------------------%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{Figure on a single page.}
\end{figure}

%%%---------------------------------------------Two page Figure---------------------%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\subcaption{}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure on two pages}
\end{figure}

% Normal figure
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{Figure on a single page.}
\end{figure}

% continued floats
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

{\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\subcaption{}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure on two pages}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

## Side by side figure

Personally I wouldn't use a `tabular`(`x`) at all for that case, but if you prefer it, just place the `tabularx` environment a `\caption` inside a `subfigure` environment, i.e.

```
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{YY}
\includegraphics{1} & \includegraphics{2} \\
First & Second
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Third layer}
\end{subfigure}
```

Here is a different suggestion:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[a4paper, width=425.196850394pt, top=70.866141732pt,bottom=70.866141732pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}  
\raggedbottom                    


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Document Begins from here %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\setlength{\@fptop}{0pt}
\setlength{\@fpbot}{0pt plus 1fil}
\makeatother


\chapter{Introduction}
This chapter is about the problem of wrong figure numbers.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
\caption{Figure on a single page.}
\end{figure}

%%%---------------------------------------------Two page Figure---------------------%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
%%mages on the new page
\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure on two pages}
\label{image}
\end{figure}

%%%--------------Tabular Figure --------%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}
%%Original image
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{example-image}
\caption{Original image}
\end{subfigure}
\par\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}

First image
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}

Second image
\end{minipage}
\caption{Third layer}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%Figure continued%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{figure}[ht]
\ContinuedFloat
 %%Second Layer
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
\centering

\begin{minipage}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}

First image
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.47\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}

Second image
\end{minipage}
\caption{Fourth layer}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Figure using Tables}
\label{image}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I have updated my question. Actually, I have to put figures using table also. I have provided the third figure too using table in my MWE. Please tell me how can I use `subcaption` in that table environment

Comment: @skm Just put the table in a `subfigure` environment? Or should `First image` and `Second image` be subcaptions?

Comment: thanks, actually the tabular environment is not necessray for this example but in my original file, I need to have four image in a single row, I need to provide them indivisual names and I need to group them. For that case, use of tabular enviornment becomes necessary. Anyways, thanks for your suggestion