# ?? instead of figure number!

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I have the following code. However whenever I use `\ref{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}` in text, I found **`??`** instead of figure number.

How can I solve the problem???

```
 \begin{figure} 
        \begin{tikzpicture}
          \caption{My Figure}
        \end{tikzpicture}

        \label{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}
 \end{figure}
```

Comment: For the figure numbering to appear correctly you have to insert a `\caption` in the figure, before the `\label`.

Comment: is the anyway other than using a \caption. it adds a figure number under my figure

Comment: But if you don't have the figure number how are you going to mention the figure number in the text?

Comment: Yes, there is, see the [dicussion here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258405/121799).

Comment: I have a tikz picture inside figure and I added the \caption inside a \node. Therefore I don't need a figure number under my figure

Comment: Hi @SadeghEskandari. May be you should add a minimal working example (MWE) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The recommended way to put a label on a `\caption` is to include the label in the mandatory argument: `\caption{This is my caption\label{fig:foo}}`. Make sure to not accidentally include whitespace before or after the `\label` though.

Comment: Your code throws some errors when embedded into a minimal document.

Comment: `\caption` has to be outside of the tikzpicture environment. I don't think `tikz` can accept a caption outside of a `minipage` and without `caption` or `subcaption` package

Comment: @koleygr `\node [text width=5cm] {\caption{foo}};` for example would work fine, because the `text width` setting of the node makes the node into a `minipage` like box.

Comment: Thanks for the info @TorbjørnT.... I will check it to see how hyperref behaves with this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to place a `\label` without a `\caption`. The required code (which is also used by `\caption`) is `\refstepcounter{<counter-type>}`. So to set a label to your figure you could use `\refstepcounter{figure}\label{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0) {Foo};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  \refstepcounter{figure}\label{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}%
\end{figure}

\ref{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}
\end{document}
```

If you already used a `\caption` (which I can't inside of `tikzpicture`) you'd get misnumbered labels this way. To compensate the additional step you could do a `\addcounter{figure}{-1}`, so the labeling code would become:

```
\addcounter{figure}{-1}\refstepcounter{figure}\label{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}
```

As @JohnKormylo mentioned a way to put a caption inside of a `tikzpicture` (surrounding it in a `minipage` or like in the following a `\parbox`) here is the proper way of setting the `\label` in that case:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node at (0,0)
      {\parbox{.8\textwidth}{\caption{Foo\label{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{figure}

\ref{PROGRAM:HELLO-WORLD}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could put a caption inside a minipage inside a node inside a tikzpicture.

Comment: @JohnKormylo haven't thought of that.

Comment: This solution solved my problem. thank you Skillmon

Comment: Possibly less cluttered: `\node [text width=0.8\textwidth] {\caption{foo\label{bar}}};`. (@JohnKormylo)

Comment: @SadeghEskandari if it solved your problem then maybe mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, you don't need to set `\textwidth=\hsize` anywhere. Not sure where you're going with the second part of the comment, you were the one who mentioned minipages in the first place. (I do see now that setting `text width` doesn't give the same output as a `minipage` or `\parbox` though, so one of the latter might be better: https://v2.overleaf.com/read/bvcbkghfgxvg)