# Why using \ContinuedFloat with a figure restarts figure number?

Tags: graphics, floats, subfig

In a chapter of my thesis, I have 3 figures where the third one consists of many subfigures that must be split over 3 pages. For that, I used `\ContinuedFloat` and works fine. The problem, however, is the figure number is 4.1 which is not what I expect; I expect 4.3 as there are two figures before this one where they have the correct numbers. The third figure is:

```
\documentclass[demo]{report} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption,graphicx,geometry}
\begin{document}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter} 
\setcounter{chapter}{4} % just for this example

\begin{figure}[tb]
    \centering
    \subfloat[FS -- Entropy]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/FS_Entropy_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:fse}%
    }
    \subfloat[FS -- Phenotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/FS_Phenotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:fsp}%
    }\par
    \subfloat[FS -- Genotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/FS_Genotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:fsg}%
    }\par
    \subfloat[CL -- Entropy]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/CL_Entropy_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:cle}%
    }
    \subfloat[CL -- Phenotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/CL_Phenotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:clp}%
    }\par
    \subfloat[CL -- Genotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/CL_Genotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:clg}%
    }\par
    \subfloat{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/legend_crop.pdf}%
        \label{fig:leg1}%
    }
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[tb]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfloat[DIP -- Entropy]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/DIP_Entropy_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:dipe}%
    }
    \subfloat[DIP -- Phenotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/DIP_Phenotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:dipp}%
    }\par
    \subfloat[DIP -- Genotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/DIP_Genotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:dipg}%
    }\par
    \subfloat[AR -- Entropy]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/AR_Entropy_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:are}%
    }
    \subfloat[AR -- Phenotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/AR_Phenotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:arp}%
    }\par
    \subfloat[AR -- Genotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/AR_Genotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:arg}%
    }\par
    \subfloat{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/legend_crop.pdf}%
        \label{fig:leg2}%
    }
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[tb]\ContinuedFloat
    \centering
    \subfloat[DE -- Entropy]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/ED_Entropy_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:dee}%
    }
    \subfloat[DE -- Phenotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/ED_Phenotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:dep}%
    }\par
    \subfloat[DE -- Genotype]{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/ED_Genotype_.pdf}%
        \label{fig:deg}%
    }\par
    \subfloat{%
        \includegraphics[width=0.6\textwidth]{Images/Chapter4/RQ2/legend_crop.pdf}%
        \label{fig:leg3}%
    }
    \caption{Different techniques with different measures}
    \label{fig:RQ2_plot}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

As I mentioned, the figure number of this is Figure 4.1 where in fact it should be Figure 4.3.

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: As always on this site please post a full minimal self contained example that others can copy and test as is. Here we don't have your images, no preamble or document class. Where does `\ContinuedFloat`  even come from?

Comment: Check https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15693/91556

Comment: I've taken the liberty of editing/augmenting your code to make it minimally compilable. If I missed or misunderstood something essential about your document setup, please do edit the code to make it consistent with your actual document setup.

Answer (score 1):

You claim,

> "... the figure number [in the third `figure` environment] is `Figure 4.1` where in fact it should be `Figure 4.3`".

Within the context of the code snippet you provided, this claim is false for two separate reasons.

1. The first and second `figure` environments don't contain `\caption` statements. Hence, they don't provide the standard mechanism for incrementing the `figure` counter. The first time a figure-related `\caption` statement is encountered is in the third `figure` environment. Hence, its number *must be* 4.1 (assuming we're in Chapter 4 and figure numbers are prefixed with the chapter number).
2. Even if the first and second `figure` environments contained `\caption` statements, their `\ContinuedFloat` statements serve to make sure that the `figure` counter is not incremented by any `\caption` directives.

What to do? I suggest you provide the directives

```
\caption{Different techniques with different measures, Part 1 of 3}
\label{fig:RQ2_plot}
```

at the top of the first `figure` environment and

```
\caption{Different techniques with different measures, Part 2 of 3}
```

and

```
\caption{Different techniques with different measures, Part 3 of 3}
```

immediately after the `\ContinuedFloat` statements in the second and third `figure` environments.

---

Of course, if I added the instruction

```
\addtocounter{figure}{2}
```

immediately before the first `figure` environment, its caption number would indeed be `4.3`, not `4.1`.